# How can I add event using link in ios google calendar

Tags: ios, swift, google-calendar-api

I am trying to add event using link(

```
https://www.google.com/calendar/render?action=TEMPLATE&dates=20210130T142900Z%2F20210131T142200Z
```

The date format is "YYYYDDMM'T'HHmmss'Z' in iOS google calendar

I have selected event start time 17:59 (07:59PM) but in iOS app it is showing 08:00PM while in android it is working fine. I have noticed it is taking approximate value of time. Any one can help me in which format i should send date time to this link.

I want to generate a link through my iOS application and will send this link to another user so that they can add event in google calendar using that link whether it is android or iOS. In android app it is working perfectly but in iOS google calendar it is not working fine.

Comment: for me the link is working fine your above link has 7:29Pm event

Comment: for your device, you have to do trouble shouting check this link
https://calendly.com/blog/how-to-fix-google-calendar-sync-problems/

Comment: @saqibkafeel appointment start time was 7:59PM not 7:29PM.